# How to compare value from previous test run with current?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, web-deployment, robotframework

I'm using [robotframework](http://robotframework.org) and Selenium via [Selenium2Library](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library)

I would like to test if value extracted from DOM element changed and is different than one checked in previous test run.

I'm thinking about using Robotframework-MongoDB-Library or other database. Next step would be adding custom mini-library for saving and retrieving extracted value for test cases.

In first test run all this kind of test will be marked as failed but next runs theoretically should work correctly.

I'm not experienced in testing field, is this right approach? If not then how can I execute this kind of tests?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad practice, as on the 2nd run (which will pass) you don't really know if that DOM is actually correct as it might be a persistent issue.

The idea is that tests are reproducible, so when something fails, you can reproduce the reason why they failed.

Also, this approach might cause an interesting behaviour change in your team: *When the tests fail, re-run them until they pass, and don't bother looking at why they failed* (I would bet good money on this :)).

Something you might want to do is to refine your test, so you only check the bits that are important, rather than the whole DOM (or a big chunk of it)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't detailed enough - what I mean by "value extracted from DOM" is for example canonical url , product name or other different short piece of data as you mentioned. Additionally next test re-run wouldnt simply replace value - I'm thinking about some kind of interface which will allow to mark this change as "valid" for next run(if this change was desired - otherwise it will be needed to fix error)